# zabbix multiple conditions "Incorrect trigger expression" error

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

What's wrong with this trigger?

```
{Template App RabbitMQ v3:rabbitmq[server,message_count_unacknowledged].last(#3)} >= 4000 And 
{Template App RabbitMQ v3:rabbitmq[server,message_count_unacknowledged].time()}<010000 And 
{Template App RabbitMQ v3:rabbitmq[server,message_count_unacknowledged].time()}>011000 And 
{Template App RabbitMQ v3:rabbitmq[server,message_count_unacknowledged].time()}>091000 And 
{Template App RabbitMQ v3:rabbitmq[server,message_count_unacknowledged].time()}<090000
```

I've got "Incorrect trigger expression" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` should be all lowercase, you have `And`.